# "Photoswipe" gallery close itself on image click in case of small image

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

By default **Photoswipe** provides zoom and drag&drop feature for large images. It works fine. But if image is smaller than viewport, click on that image will close a gallery.

Video of this trouble:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22619948/photoswipe-click-close.mov
```

Demo made by plugin author:
http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM
(possible to change image size at 6th line)

I want to provide "go to next image" function by clicking on image. I found solution here: https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/747
It works but gallery still close itself if image is small.

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a respond from plugin author on github link above.
Solution:

```
clickToCloseNonZoomable: false
```